# Filtering results based on keyword, category, and search location in yelp API

Tags: yelp

I know that there is Yelp API available to fetch business locations by keyword, category, and location but I am having little problem here.

Please check this screenshot.
[image]

User is going to select either lunch, dinner, or drink PLUS a city in which he wants listing of restaurants. Now I can use "lunch", "dinner" or "drink" as keyword and make an API call for given selected city and system will send me 20 businesses.

The problem is that I want user to given facility to auto suggest the business names as user types in first few character of business names. But as I have just 20 results, I can not suggest the name if it is does not present in the list of 20 fetched. So what should be the best way in order accomplish this functionality?

Comment: what you say??i don't get it

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to serve an Autocomplete unfortunately, Yelp api does not provide that, you can try to use another api, like Google Places.

You can limit your search on the query parameters on your yelp search

```
https://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?location=San Francisco, CA&limit=100
```